# EF Core 6 - The Linq Expression could not be translated. Trying to check details of linked property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am trying to use the specification pattern in our solution to share some common logic. One of the queries I have is trying to use a specification written for a linked property within a query for the main object, but I am getting the error "The linq expression could not be translated". I understand this is because SQl doesn't know about my own functions, but it would be helpful to utilise the specification in order to prevent the duplication of logic.

Take the below simplified example:

```
public abstract class Specification<T>
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity)
    {
        Func<T, bool> predicate = ToExpression().Compile();
        return predicate(entity);
    }

    public abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldInclude { get; set; }
}

public sealed class IncludeBarSpecification : Specification<Bar>
{
    public override Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        return bar => bar.ShouldInclude;
    }
}

public static class IncludeSpecificationExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Bar> IncludeBar(this IQueryable<Bar> bars)
    {
        var specification = new IncludeBarSpecification ();
        return bars.Where(specification.ToExpression());
    }
}
```

Assume I want to write a function to return a series of Foos, and I should only return Foos where all of their associated Bars should be included.

As a normal query this might be something like

```
await context.Foos.Where(x => !x.Bars.Any(a => !a.ShouldInclude)).ToListAsync;
```

How can I write that instead to use the IncludeBarSpecification?

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
await context.Foos.Where(x => !x.Bars.Any(a => !a.IncludeBar())).ToListAsync;
```

Comment: You can't compose queryables like you are attempting to do.  The reason is `x.Bars.Any(a => !a.IncludeBar())` -- the predicate is lost by this point (it's just an `IQueryable<Bar>`, not an expression tree) and is not part of your enclosing `Where` clause.  You'll have to compose those expression trees yourself or else use something like [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```cs
await context.Foos
    .Where(x => !x.Bars.AsQueryable().IncludeBar().Any())
    .ToListAsync();
```